# Can we create a space in which density of all electromagnetic fields is 0?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, general-relativity

so i was just thinking that may be the reason of that we cannot measure a quantum particle position and velocity may be because continuously it's being hit by electromagnetic radiation and since we need light which is electromagnetic radiation to measure the position and velocity of light so since the light has already deviated particle from it's position so therefore we cannot measure it accurately so o thought if we could make a space region which have no electromagnetic wave then may  be somehow we can test that is the particle have definite position or not.

Comment: [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage)

Answer (score 0):

Can we create spaces that are free of electromagnetic influence? It is possible to create spaces free from electromagnetic influence to some degree of tolerance that has been a priori specified. However, this would not allow us to measure the position and momentum of a particle with any degree of precision. These quantities would still be limited by the Heisenberg uncertainty principle.

For example, in the Copenhagen school of thought, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle is understood as the result of a macroscopic system (experimental apparatus) interacting with a microscopic system (e.g. electron or atom). Whatever you use to probe the electron in order to measure it, will also disturb it. It is odd and it is disconcerting, however, the Heisenberg uncertainty principle cannot be avoided.